# Make batch file runnable only in a specific location

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file for my own use. The batch file itself has been added to my path so it can easily be run on the command line.

I only want to be able to run this command if my current location on the command line is something specific. i.e. I only want the file to be runable/usable if my location in the command window is something like `C:\FolderA`, and not runnable anywhere else, including in any subdirectories, so it would not work in `C:\FolderA\FolderB` or `C:\FolderC`. If the location doesn't match the "approved" location then a simple error should be thrown.

Is there an easy-ish way to do this? I am very new to batch-files so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use the system variable `%cd%` to check what the current working directory is.

Comment: could add more detail/context. I'm really new to this so don't know how to use it

Comment: Put the batch file inside `C:\FolderA` then, not inside `%Path%`. Whenever you're inside `C:\FolderA`, i.e it is your current directory, you can just type the scripts name, _(preferably with its file extension, to avoid using `%PATHEXT%`)_. If you're not in that directory, entering its name will never work, because the file would not be found.

Comment: Ah yes obviously! Thank-you. Feel free to put that as the answer and I will accept it

Comment: Furthermore, I'd suggest that you use this as the new first line of that batch file, _(just shift everything else down a line)_: `@SetLocal EnableExtensions & CD /D "%~dp0"`. This will ensure that the batch script will always only function with the correct working directory from the outset.

Comment: But, of course entering `c:\foldera\batchname` would still run the batch, regardless of the current directory, Possibly if the first active command was `pushd "c:\FolderA" there'd be little doubt. Perhaps precede that with `md C:\FolderA 2>nul` and `if not exist "C:\FolderA\. goto :eof` might be a belt-and-braces approach.

Comment: @Compo's answer is great but if you want the batch-file to be able to run from command prompt then the approach won't work .but i have put a batch file in answer that will work even if it's added in `%Path%`.

Comment: I was careful to read the question, @Justaus3r. They want the batch file to run by typing only its name when the current working directory in the Command Prompt, is `C:\FolderA`. Putting it in that directory, and not having that location in `%Path%` will ensure that it is only run by typing just its name, when the current directory is correct. Yes it could be run by not typing just its name, and including its location, i.e. `C:\FolderA\mybatch`, when the current directory is anything else, hence the reason, for those scenarios, I suggested they include the line to force that current directory.

Comment: As an alternative, they should use the method suggested by @Squashman, e.g. `@Setlocal EnableExtensions & If /I Not "%CD%\" == "%~dp0" Exit /B`, which would just prevent the script from running the rest of the code within, should the current directory not be that of the batch files location, i.e. `C:\FolderA`. Alternatively `@Setlocal EnableExtensions & If /I Not "%CD%" == "C:\FolderA" Exit /B`, to use the full absolute path instead.

Comment: @Compo yes that would work perfectly.the method suggested by Squashman is great but they want to throw a simple error if not executed from desired location so that's why i added a simple error message they can improve it to their needs

Comment: An error message has little worth in this case though @Justaus3r. If the OP intends to only run it by name when the correct directory is current, and it is in that directory, then it will always run. If the directory is not current, and it isn't located in `%Path%`, then when they type its name, they'd get a message from cmd.exe telling them that `'mybatch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` They do not need anything else, unless they try to run it with `C:\FolderA\mybatch`, which is not what the question specfically asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do such a thing by using the %cd% system variable which returns current directory then you can compare that with the directory  you want the batch file to be executable.here is a simple batch file that will do the work.

```
@echo off
rem replace the path with yours
if "%cd%"=="D:\WinPwnage" goto continue
goto error
:error
echo You are not in that specific location
rem just to sleep for 5 seconds
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
exit
:continue
echo Your code
pause >nul
```

**Edit:**

@Squashman reminded that the single qoutes wont work with special characters so i edited it.

Comment: Single quotes do not protect spaces and special characters in file paths.  The `IF` command will fail. You need to use "double quotes".

Comment: Let me recommend to do case-insensitive comparison for paths: `if /I "%CD%"=="…" …`…